How to Bind Image Class into Xaml WPF?
I have a class library which contains Images. This class library is being referred in another WPF solution where i need to access this Images. I tried several methods, but other than the relative path, i am not able to access it diretly. I am doing something wrong here, but couldnt understand what.
I am listing the screenshots of the project structure and the UI. Please help.
UI Design
Icons Library code
My requirement is to access the Object directly inside the XAML as x:type or the class name instead of the relative path.
I tried a lot of ways to access it, but i dont know what way to access the Image class inside the library directly.
<Style x:Key="FeatureGroupIconStyle" TargetType="Image">            
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/IconsLibrary;component/UI-48/Computer.png"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Source={x:Type icons:Computer}, Path=Source,Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter}}" />-->
    <!--<Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Source={x:Type icons:Computer},Path= Source}"/>-->
    <!--<Setter Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey={x:Type icons:Computer}}"/>-->    
</Style>

Every line except the first one isnt working.

Why would you not simply use instances of the Computer and ComputerNew classes instead of trying to access their Source properties in an Image Style? None of your attempts would actually create such an instance. Besides that, it is unclear why you have this approach at all. The common way to load an image file from a referenced assembly is by means of a Resource File Pack URI.

Create User Controls (in the class librry) for each Image Control and image in question, and access them that way. i.e. the "pathing" stays in the (class) library.

This is a sample project i created to check how i can switch between two images on data triggers. The image was not getting binded properly so i was trying to see how i can bind an image first.

Please do not post links to images of code.  Post the code in the body of the message, properly formatted

Be aware that you would also have to use Resource File Pack URIs including the assembly name in the library's ResourceDictionary, i.e. Value="/IconsLibrary;component/UI-48/Computer.png" instead of Value="../UI-48/Computer.png".
